# (Python/MATLAB) How to generate Bivariate (or multivariate) BERNOULLI Distributed Samples?

Tags: probability-distributions, matlab, binomial-distribution, python, multivariate-statistical-analysis

I am trying to generate samples of Bivariate/Multivariate Bernoulli Distributions in Python or MATLAB. How to go about it?

Given: Mean of the distribution and the Number of samples to be generated.

Any inbuilt functions or libraries that can help me in this?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.bernoulli.html

Comment: @WilliamM. This cannot generate MULTIVARIATE Bernoulli.

Comment: What is the definition of a multivariate Bernoulli?

Comment: Do you mean Multinomial?

Comment: Yes. Eventually I want to that way.